# Unable to connect to MongoDB on EC2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

Unable to connect MongoDB (Version 4.0.5) on EC2 (Windows Server 2018)

I have tried all the options.
1) Modify mongod.cfg with
     net:
    port: 27017
    bindIp: 0.0.0.0
    bindIpAll: true
2) start with mongod --bind_all_ip
3) My security group on EC2 has allowed 27017 port inbound for 0.0.0.0/0.
I'm trying to connect through terminal 
    mongo mongodb://*********.compute.amazonaws.com:27017

However, I get following exception when connecting through mongo shell

```
mongodb://e*******.compute.amazonaws.com:27017/? 
gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2019-01-21T15:51:11.044-0800 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect 
to server *****.compute.amazonaws.com:27017, connection attempt 
failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 
******.compute.amazonaws.com:27017 (54.244.203.203:27017) :: caused by 
:: Operation timed out :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:328:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

What else I need to do?

Also, it seems my mongodb.cfg has no effect on the server. When I start server with above change in cfg file, I get the warning in server console that the server is bound to localhost, regardless. Starting the server with mongod --bind_all_ip gets rid of that warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firewall was the problem. Need to open port 27017 by running WF.msc from run command on Windows. Spent a whole day trying to figuring out all other options. I still don't know how to get the mongod.cfg working for all ip addresses. I need to run mongod with --bind_all_ip option for that.